# space invader pygame make enemy disappear when shot

Tags: python, pygame

I have a list with all my enemies and when the distance between the players bullet and the enemy is close enough, I can make a enemy disappear but its never the right one that was hit with the bullet, its always the enemy with the greatest x value(in my case the one at the end of the list) so my questions is how do I make the specific enemy disappear. here is my code for reference.

```
import pygame
import random
import math

# initalize pygame
pygame.init()

# creates game screen to display game
game_window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 570))

# Title and icon for window
pygame.display.set_caption("Power of the Doctor")
icon = pygame.image.load('tardisShooter.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# backgroun picture
background = pygame.image.load('SpaceTardissmall.png')

# player info
Playerimg = pygame.image.load('tardisShooter.png')
playerx = 370  # players x axis
playery = 470  # players y axis
playerx_change = 0  # adds constant change while added in loop


def player(x, y):
    # blit draws image on screen: x axis  y axis
    game_window.blit(Playerimg, (x, y))


# enemy info
Enemyimg = []
enemyx = []
enemyy = []
enemyx_change = 1
enemyy_change = 0
num_enemies = 2
enemyspawnx = 50
enemyspawny = 200
for i in range(num_enemies):
    Enemyimg.append(pygame.image.load('CybermanShooter.png'))
    enemyx.append(enemyspawnx)  # random x axis for enemy
    enemyy.append(enemyspawny)  # random y axis for enemy
    enemyspawnx += 70


def enemy(x, y, i):
    game_window.blit(Enemyimg[i], (x, y))


# bullet info
bulletimg = pygame.image.load('torpedo32.png')
bullety = playery
bulletx = playerx
bulletstate = "idle"
bullety_change = 5


def bullet(x, y):
    global bulletstate
    bulletstate = "FIRE"
    game_window.blit(bulletimg, (x + 15.5, y - 25))


def collision(enemyx, enemyy, bulletx, bullety):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(bulletx - enemyx, 2)) + (math.pow(bullety - enemyy, 2)))

    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


rand = random.randint(0, num_enemies)

# timer info
bulletevent = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(bulletevent, 2000)

# get a rabdom number
# when the timer hits 2 secodsn spawsn bomb at the index of the random number that corresponds witht the enemy


# enemy bomb
bombimg = []
bombx = []
bomby = []
bomby_change = 1
bombstate = "idle"
num_bombs = 2
for i in range(num_bombs):
    bombimg.append(pygame.image.load('bomb.png'))
    bombx.append(enemyx[i])
    bomby.append(enemyy[i])


def bomb(x, y, i):
    global bombstate
    bombstate = "fire"
    game_window.blit(bombimg[i], (x + 15, y + 65))


# player hit detection
def enemyhit(bombx, bomby, x, y):
    distance2 = math.sqrt((math.pow(bombx - x, 2)) + (math.pow(bomby - (y - 50), 2)))

    if distance2 < 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# loop to keep screen running
Running = True
while Running:
    # background color
    game_window.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # background image in loop
    game_window.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # checks anything typed while game is running
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # if they click x to quit close window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False

        if event.type == bulletevent:
            if bombstate == 'idle':
                bomb(bombx[rand], bomby[rand], i)
                bombx[rand] = enemyx[rand]
                bomby[rand] = enemyy[rand]

        # means key has been pressed(not released)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # escape key closes game
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                Running = False

            # right key moves player 5 spaces
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerx_change = 5

            # left key moves players back 5 spaces
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerx_change = -5

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bulletx = playerx
                if bulletstate == "idle":
                    bullet(bulletx, bullety)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerx_change = 0

    playerx += playerx_change  # constantly adds user input to player model
    # player bounds
    if playerx >= 740:
        playerx = 740
    if playerx <= 0:
        playerx = 0

    # player fucntion draws image
    player(playerx, playery)

    # loops through all the items in the lists named
    for i in range(num_enemies):
        # draws all enemies
        enemy(enemyx[i], enemyy[i], i)
        enemyx[i] += enemyx_change

        if enemyx[i] >= 735:
            enemyx_change = -.8
            enemyy[i] += 10

        if enemyx[i] <= 0:
            enemyx_change = .8
            enemyy[i] += 10

    # is state is fire
    if bulletstate == "FIRE":
        # draws torpepd at coordinates

        bullet(bulletx, bullety)
        bullety -= bullety_change  # decreases y axis moving bullet

    if bullety <= 0:  # if goes past border
        bulletstate = "idle"  # ittl switch back to idle
        bullety = playery  # moves bullet y back to player y

    for i in range(num_enemies):
        collided = collision(enemyx[i], enemyy[i], bulletx, bullety)
        if collided == True:
            bulletstate = 'idle'
            bullety = playery
            Enemyimg.remove(Enemyimg[i])
            num_enemies -= 1

    # when enemy fires
    if bombstate == 'fire':
        bomb(bombx[rand], bomby[rand], i)
        bomby[rand] += bomby_change
        if bomby[rand] > 570:
            bombstate = 'idle'
            bomby[rand] = enemyy[rand]
            rand = random.randint(0, 1)

    # enemy bullets hit player
    enemyhits = enemyhit(bombx[rand], bomby[rand], playerx, playery)
    if enemyhits == True:
        playerx = 370
        bombstate = 'idle'
        bomby[rand] = enemyy[rand]

    # updates the screen in loop
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You've got a lot of code there, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big problem with your code is having different lists for each attribute of your enemies.

You wrote this :

```py
Enemyimg = []
enemyx = []
enemyy = []
```

Meaning that you always need to sync those three lists at all time to get coherent results. Which you are not doing, when you "remove" an enemy, you just remove the img from `Enemyimg` and not removing its coords in `enemyy` and `enemyx`.
While you could manage to make it work with three lists, you are just overcomplicating things. Let me show you what you may want to do to make your life way easier :)

---

I'm going to assume, you don't know about OOP (Object Oriented Programming) yet ? I Would be a great time to use it but it can be a little complexe if you are just starting out with programming.

So let's introduce **python's dict** !

What you really want to do is have one single list :

```py
enemies = []
```

But how to store everything in one list you might wonder ?

Well, it will be a list of dict. A dict looks something like that :

```py
example = {'image': pygame.image.load('CybermanShooter.png'), 'x': enemyspawnx, 'y': enemyspawny}
```

*(Note that if you always use the same image, you don't need to put it here, you can just draw your image at the position)*

Now if you do something like :

```py
print(example['x'])
```

It will print your enemy's x value.

---

**So, to sum up :**

1. You want to have one single list : `enemies = []`
2. To add an enemy you will do :

```py
enemies.append({'image': pygame.image.load('CybermanShooter.png'), 'x': enemyspawnx, 'y': enemyspawny})
```

3. To detect your collisions :

```py
# Your collision function
def collision(enemy, bulletx, bullety):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(bulletx - enemy['x'], 2)) + (math.pow(bullety - enemy['y'], 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    return False

# Your loop (in 2 steps: 1 - find enemies to remove, 2 - actually remove them)
enemies_to_remove = []
for enemy in enemies :
    if collision(enemy, bulletx, bullety):
        bulletstate = 'idle'
        bullety = playery
        enemies_to_remove.append(enemy)
        num_enemies -= 1

for enemy in enemies_to_remove:
    enemies.remove(enemy)
```

4. To draw your enemies:

```py
# Your draw_enemy function (which you called `enemy(...)` for some reason)
def draw_enemy(enemy):
    game_window.blit(enemy['image'], (enemy['x'], enemy['y']))

# Inside the main loop
for enemy in enemies:
    draw_enemy(enemy)
```

5. To update the position of enemies:

```py
# Make a move_enemy function
def move_enemy(enemy):
    # put your moving logic here

# Inside the main loop:
for enemy in enemies:
    move_enemy(enemy)
```

Do you get the principle ?
I've tried to stay as close as your original code as possible so it's not too many information to take in at once.

But technically you should apply the same principle for your bullets and to some extend to your player.

Comment: I appreciate the help with dict It has made my code more efficient. I Have a question regarding the removal of the specific items in the list when I use this code. for i in range(num_enemies):
       draw_enemy(enemies,i)
       if collision(enemies[i]['x'],bulletx,enemies[i]['y'],bullety,i) == True:
        enemies.remove(enemies[i])
        num_enemies -= 1
it only lets me remove the last enemy in the list, I understand because if I use the index I the last one is the one being targeted but im not sure how to change this.

Comment: If you are using dicts, you should prefer using for each loops over for loops. Hence to iter through your items, you'd do : `for enemy in enemies:` then you can simply pass your enemy var to collision like I did in the example I gave you. Add the enemies to be deleted in a new list then go through the list of enemy to remove and remove them from your main `enemies` list. I'd suggest you read my answer one more time since this is better explained above.